# ajax replace body with jQuery load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i try to replace the body with following code using jquery.

```
let url = $(id_mobileform).attr(attr_action) + " #MobileBody";

$('#MobileBody').load(
    url,
    $(id_mobileform).serialize(),
    function(response, status, xhr) {
        if (status == "success") {
            alert("yay i have a good response.. but I still don't do it. :p");
        }

        if (status == "error") {
            alert(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
        }
    }
);
```

That's remove the inner body stuff. status is success and and response have the full html page.

Otherway

```
let url = $(id_mobileform).attr(attr_action) + " #MobileBody";

$.post(
    url,
    $(id_mobileform).serialize(),
    function(data) {
        $("form").replaceWith(data);
    }
);
```

thats put full html page between body.

So load doesn't load and the selector in the url var is ignored.

why is that? maybe there is another way?

Answer (score 0):

Use following code with $.ajax function to load/replace the content.

```
var formdata = new FormData($("#id_mobileform")[0]);
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: formdata,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    type: 'POST',
    beforeSend: function () {
        // Loading
    },
    success: function (response) {
        // alert("yay i have a good response.. but I still don't do it. :p");
        // Do action to replace content
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }

});
```